# How to connect to MongoDB via the .Net driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I'm following this example, [ClientMongo](https://github.com/alanning/MongoProviders/blob/master/MongoProviders/ClientMongo.cs) to connect a WPF application to my MongoDB database via the connection string. But I get an error on the MongoClient when I call the `GetServer` method. The error states that `GetServer` doesn't exist, although the correct using references and usings have been added.

Can anyone spot if I've missed a step in setting this up? Or is there an alternative solution to create a connection with the remote DB?

This is the code I've used to connect, similar to the example above. The user and password have been starred out for privacy:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoDBApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string connectionString = "mongodb://<brian****>:<********123;>@ds048878.mongolab.com:48878/orders";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var mongoUrl = MongoUrl.Create(connectionString);
            var server = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetServer();
            return server.GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [These](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/) docs are of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the 2.x Version of the C# driver, forget about the Server object. 
You can get your Database directly from the client:

```
var client = new MongoClient("<connectionString>");
return this.Client.GetDatabase("<databaseName>");
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mention I'm using this version http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/   2.1.0

Comment: The 2.1 docs for anyone else interested:  http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/getting_started/quick_tour/